# Array of strings in Ada

Tags: arrays, string, ada

So, I'm coding in Ada for the first time and have to create this pre-populated array of strings, so I can use a random method and call a different value each time.

```
poolOfWords: constant array(1..50) of string := ("gum","sin","for","cry","lug","bye","fly",
                "ugly", "each","from","work","talk","with","self", "pizza","thing","feign","friend",
                 "elbow","fault", "dirty","budget","spirit","quaint","maiden","escort","pickax",
                 "example","tension","quinine","kidney","replica","sleeper", "triangle","kangaroo",
                 "mahogany","sergeant","sequence","moustache","dangerous","scientist",
                 "different","quiescent", "magistrate","erroneously","loudspeaker",
                 "phytotoxic","matrimonial","parasympathomimetic","thigmotropism");
```

But when I try to compile I get this error: "unconstrained element type in array declaration".

I Googled all over internet and couldn't find a solution to that. I even tried to use unbounded_string, but didn't work as well. It works fine when I pre-populate an array of integers, floats, but when it come to strings it's not working.

Can someone help me and explain what's going on and how to solve it? I really don't want to declare the array and then populate each of the 50 indexes one by one.

Comment: The basic problem is obvious : the strings are of different sizes, so they cannot be stored in the same array. Define "didn't work as well" for unbounded_string. It's possibly the best solution here (though bounded_string constrained to the length of the longest member would also be a good option). Use either of those, work through their difficulties, and ask (with more detail) if you get stuck.

Comment: @BrianDrummond but if I use unbounded_string, it gives an error saying that I'm trying to assign a string to an unbounded_string array, and I **think** the solution to that would be to use the To_Unbounded_String() in each element of the pre-populated array... Right?

Comment: Right. Constant strings (i.e. "something") must be converted to unbounded strings to initialize the array

Comment: Yep. You can rename To_Unbounded_String to "+" to make your life easier.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you guys so much!!!

Comment: `function "+" (Source : String) return Unbounded_String renames To_Unbounded_String;`. You can also shorten `Unbounded_String` to make your life even easier (example here: https://github.com/zertovitch/hac/blob/master/src/hal.ads )

Comment: Then `:= (+"gum", +"sin", +"for",...`

Comment: @PatriciaCortezzi If you feel like wrapping this collective effort (some of it's your own work) into an answer, do so. It'll make the Q more useful for others, and it's fine to accept it in a day or two if nobody provides a better one. Comments tend to go away with time...

Comment: Indeed, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188). See also these related [Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bada%5d%20Array%20of%20strings).

Answer (score 4):

Your problem stems from the fact that `String`  in Ada is an *unconstrained type*. This means, roughly, that you need to specify "something" in order to have a usable type.  In the case of `String` you need to specify the string length, since a `String` is just an array of `Character`.  If you say something like

```
 X : String;
```

the compiler complains since it does not know the length of `X` and it does not know how much memory to reserve for `X`.  You need to say something like

```
  X : String(1..6);
```

or something like

```
  X : String := "foobar";
```

Note that in the second case you do not need to specify the index range since the compiler is able to deduce it from the fact that you use a 6-`Character` string to initialize `X`.

This explains why it is illegal to declare an array of just `String`.  When you declare an array the compiler needs to know the size of every entry (all the entries must share the same size, this makes access to a random entry of the array very efficient).  If you declare an array of just `String`, the compiler would not know how much memory to allocate to every entry since the length is unspecified.

Note that this instead would work (disclaimer: I have not an Ada compiler at hand now, so I cannot check the code)

```
subtype ZIP_Code is String (1..5);
type ZIP_Code_Array is array(Positive range <>) of ZIP_Code;
```

since now the compiler knows the size of every entry of a `ZIP_Code_Array` (5 `Character`).

In your case, however, the strings have all different sizes.  I can see two possible solutions

1. If the maximum length is known in advance you can use the `subtype` approach shown above and pad the strings with spaces.  It depends on your context if this is a suitable solution or not
2. The approach that I typically use is to create an array of `Unconstrained_String` that I initialize as follows

   ```
   function "+"(X: String) return Unbounded_String
       renames To_Unbounded_String; 

   poolOfWords: constant array(1..50) of Unbounded_String := 
       (+"gum",
        +"sin",
        +"for",
         -- and so on...
       );
   ```

Note the `renames` that defines the unary `+` as an *alias* for `To_Unbounded_String`.  This is just syntactic sugar that allows you to write `+"gum"` instead of `To_Unbounded_String("gum")`. Someone cringes at this type of syntactic sugar (and I am not so keen either), but in this case I think it is worth since it makes the code "lighter."  It would be nice to have the definition of unary `+` near its use, just for clarity.

An alternative to the use of `Unbounded_String` is to use the generic package `Bounded_Strings` and define `poolOfWords` as an array of `Bounded_String`.  A `Bounded_String` can hold strings with variable length, as long as the length is smaller than the bound specified when instantiating the `Bounded_Strings` package.  In order to convert back and forth `String` you can use the same "rename trick."

My personal preference goes to the `Unbounded_String`, unless I have some special reason that forces me to use the `Bounded_String`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use Ada's standard containers. For example:

```ada
Package String_Holder is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Holders(
   "="          => Ada.Strings.Equal_Case_Insensitive,
   Element_Type => String
  );
Function "+"( Right : String_Holder.Holder ) return String
  renames String_Holder.Element;
Function "+"( Right : String ) return String_Holder.Holder
  renames String_Holder.To_Holder;
```

Allows you to store in the holder varying sized values of type `String`, so you could forego any dependence on `Ada.Strings.Unbounded_String` and use something like:

```ada
poolOfWords: constant array(Positive range <>) of String_Holder.Holder := 
  +"gum", +"sin", +"for", +"cry", -- ...
  +"Stuff"
  );
```

Function Get_Word(Index : Positive) return String is
(+poolOfWords(Index)) with Pre => Index in poolOfWords'Range;

Alternatively, you could use `Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors` like so:

```ada
Package String_Vector is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors(
   "="          => Ada.Strings.Equal_Case_Insensitive,
   Index_Type   => Positive,
   Element_Type => String
  );
```

though there is one problem with this in Ada 2012: You can't initialize such a vector directly within the declaration, but *can* initialize it via function-call:

```ada
Function Populate return String_Vector.Vector is
Begin
   Return Result : String_Vector.Vector do
      Result.Append( "some" );
      Result.Append( "data" );
      Result.Append( "HERE" );
   End Return;
End Populate;
```

Being able to say `X : String_Vectors.Vector := ("this", "that", "the other")` is in Ada 2020 .